# User access restriction website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, web

I am developing an web app in Python using GAP and I have multiple users, each with it's own resources.

What I want to know is, if user `A` has a resource at `/A/resource/` how can I restrict access to user `B` to that resource ?

I was thinking doing to by using cookies, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the users service:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers

You can leverage the security that google provide for signing in etc.

Then for each resource, track what "users" owns it and only serve it to that user and that user alone.

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if user == valid_user_for_this_resource:
    #serve resource
else:
    #deny access
```

Otherwise you can roll your own login service and validate like that.

Comment: I am running my own logging service. What I wanted to know is how to I verify that the User that accesses that resource, owns it. Only through cookies ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "logging service" (log in service!). I've done a similar system where each user's resource file also contains the user that created that resource. Then when a resource is asked for I check the current logged in user via the users service, compare that to the "owner" of the resource and if they match, serve it. If you want to use cookies then perhaps have a look at webapp2 sessions, it'll probably be much easier then re-implementing that. http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

Comment: No, not "only through cookies" - you can do it any number of ways. You could create a special unique URL (via UUID calls) that is given only to the owner of the resource - security by obscurity. That's not actually that much different from a cookie. I can copy your cookie and pretend to be you, I can copy that unique URL and pretend to be you BUT I can't copy your users ID from the users service and pretend to be you, I MUST be logged in.....

Comment: but I see what you are saying now. TBH I don't know, I can only say what I've used. As I said above, you can create a very long URL that is unique to the owner of a resource, no cookies required. Perhaps someone else will have an idea, I'll upvote your question.

Comment: If all your users have different IP's you could use that instead, or a combination of browser, IP etc to make a unique(ish) token that you track the users with to keep them "logged in" once authenticated. No cookie required.

Comment: I thought about that to. But I don't think that scales very well.